# How can i make my material more prominent?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, light

i'm trying to make a scene based in a spacecraft and a planet, but as you can see, some parts of the spacecraft seems really dark, and they appear in the render almost as if they dont exist.
How can i make them more prominent, or give them maybe more lighting? But at the same time without interfering with the background planet? maybe with two different layers and a new point based light? or self-illumination, if that's the case how can i do that on Cycles? Is it possible to make it appear, with a good reflection based on the background too?

[image]

**Reference**

[image]

Comment: For fairer and easier comparison please include your rendered spacecraft image the same size as the NASA image.  The position of planets and spacecraft should be similar.

Comment: I can't really do that, the reference it's only due to the somehow 'brightnes' of the spacecraft, ignoring the background, i'm not actually trying to do a true realistic image, but i do not want to see the model being too dark that almost shows itself like a shadow.

Answer (score 2):

- Consider reflective glossy surfaces as dominates the NASA spacecraft.  Which is making me hungry for Jiffy Pop.
- Viewer visible light fixtures are an option.  Viewer means the person seeing your image. You must judge the technical and artistic merit.
- Viewer invisible lights are an option.  Plane with EMISSION material.  Diffuse materials are to complement. Specular at your own risk. Consider parenting the light plane to the spacecraft.  To make them invisible to the user set the object option ... Visibility Panel ...  [Camera] to unchecked false.
- Consider scaling the diffuse component.
- Consider light groups for Blender Render.

Comment: I think the Emission material helps here, but as a direct material on the material's object, but actually maybe if i parent the light plane to the spacecraft it will work better. I'll try this option, thanks.